# How do I change the root directory for jupyter lab when using google cloud compute's Deep Learning VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab, google-dl-platform

I have successfully set up a GCP instance from the "Deep Learning Virtual Machine Image" as directed by [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/).  I have an ipython notebook file in the following path:

`/home/myname/my-notebook.ipynb`

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/` on my web browser, the jupyter UI shows fine, but the only directory that I can access is `/opt/deeplearning/workspace/tutorials`.

I have tried using `file > "Open From Path..."`, but the UI says that the file is not found.

How do I access a notebook that I am storing in `/home/myname/`?

Comment: One way to get around this is to change 8080 in the second line in [this script](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter) to 8888.  Then when you ssh into your vm, you can just run `jupyter notebook` and go to http://localhost:8888 on your local machine's browser.

Comment: by running "jupyter notebook", you have started a *second* Jupyter Lab instance. This is a bit wasteful

Answer (score 2):

Can you softlink your home directory from the directory that's mapped as the home directory of Jupyter?

i.e. ssh to the machine and do:

```
ln -s  /home/myname  /opt/deeplearning/workspace/tutorials/
```

Then, your notebooks should show up in Jupyter as 'myname' directory.